# Allign vertices to viewing angle

Tags: modeling

I know how to allign vertices or faces to a certain axis , but how can I allign them to the viewing angle ?
See picture , I want the selected vertices in the sphere to be alligned to the view ing angle 
 [image]

Answer (score 3):

Using the *View* Transform orientation from the 3D View header pulldown menu.

Then scale the vertex to zero in the view direction by pressing <kbd>S</kbd> then pressing <kbd>Z</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd> twice to transform along view direction local Z axis.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

solved , looptools : flatten/view  does the job

Comment: Could you add more details to your answer. Perhaps a short description of the process along with some images

Comment: It's o.k Looptools diid the job, and the transform orientation set to view